# Visual Studio Code on ubuntu not working os.environ

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

It seems that something wrong with os environment variables in Visual Studio Code(v1.1.1) on Ubuntu (v14.04.4)
I created test.py:

```
import os

print ('start')
keys = [key for key in os.environ]
for key in sorted(keys):
    print(key,'=',os.environ[key])    
print ('end')
```

that outputs in debug console only start/end (and working good in the terminal)

Is there some fix of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's either an issue with VS Code or the Python extension. I've filed an issue against the Python repository so subscribe to that for updates :)

https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/140

Comment: Thank for reporting the issue Daniel, this has been resolved (resolved on May 22).